# Add HTML elements before and after text coming from the database using js

Tags: javascript, html

Like what you see in the picture, this problem that I tried to solve and I did not know how to search for it, so I drew it. I would like to put a text in the HTML language before every point and every element brings information from the database I mean by the data point is `r[4] + r[5]`

```
const column11 = document.createElement('p');

column11.setAttribute('class', 'card-text');
column11.textContent = 'Other' + r[4] + r[5]; // r[4] and r[5] should be wrapped with <code></code>
```

[image]

Comment: Please instead of image post it as code

Comment: It's unclear what kind of diagram you posted and how to interpret it. Please post the code you have now and the desired result / explanation what is wrong. See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// Database array
const r = [,,,,'Text', 'Text']


const column11 = document.createElement('p');

column11.setAttribute('class', 'card-text');
column11.textContent = 'Other ';

const code1 = document.createElement('code');
code1.textContent = r[4];

const code2 = document.createElement('code');
code2.textContent = r[5];

column11.appendChild(code1);
column11.appendChild(code2);

document.body.appendChild(column11);
```